# Clear a Model class

Tags: android, pojo

I have a model class "JobPostBean" which I'm initiating in another model class and adding data using the second model class. I would like to clear any data which gets saved in the  "JobPostBean" class. Is there any way to clear it either in "JobPostBean" class or in the second model class where its initialised? I would prefer to clear it using a single method rather than setting every item in the "JobPostBean" class to null.

```css
public class BidNextJobDataModel {
    private static BidNextJobDataModel ourInstance = new BidNextJobDataModel();

    public static BidNextJobDataModel getInstance() {
        return ourInstance;
    }

    private BidNextJobDataModel() {

    }

    
    public UserBean userBean;
    // Here I initialised the class
    public JobPostBean jobPostBean = new JobPostBean();

    public ArrayList<FilterModel> filterModelArrayList = new ArrayList<FilterModel>();
    public ArrayList<FilterModel> notificationModelArrayList = new ArrayList<FilterModel>();
    public ArrayList<FilterModel> chooseCategoryArrayList = new ArrayList<FilterModel>();
    public ArrayList<JobsBean> jobsBeanArrayList = new ArrayList<JobsBean>();

   
}
```

```html
public class JobPostBean {
    private String jobtype="";
    private String days="";
    private String hour="";
    private String title="";
    private String category="";
    private String categorytxt="";
    private String description="";
    private String price="";
    private String duration="";
    private String is_certified="";
    private String is_insure="";
    private String is_experience="";
    private String address="";
    private String name="";
    private String image="";
    private String date="";
    private String pricetype="";

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getJobtype() {
        return jobtype;
    }

    public void setJobtype(String jobtype) {
        this.jobtype = jobtype;
    }

    public String getDays() {
        return days;
    }

    public void setDays(String days) {
        this.days = days;
    }

    public String getHour() {
        return hour;
    }

    public void setHour(String hour) {
        this.hour = hour;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public String getCategorytxt() {
        return categorytxt;
    }

    public void setCategorytxt(String categorytxt) {
        this.categorytxt = categorytxt;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
    public String getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }

    public void setDuration(String duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    public String getIs_certified() {
        return is_certified;
    }

    public void setIs_certified(String is_certified) {
        this.is_certified = is_certified;
    }

    public String getIs_insure() {
        return is_insure;
    }

    public void setIs_insure(String is_insure) {
        this.is_insure = is_insure;
    }

    public String getIs_experience() {
        return is_experience;
    }

    public void setIs_experience(String is_experience) {
        this.is_experience = is_experience;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getPricetype() {
        return pricetype;
    }

    public void setPricetype(String pricetype) {
        this.pricetype = pricetype;
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean save in another class? you can remove any item from list after inserting it to another.

Comment: If you simply instantiate the model class again it'll get new reference and the previous data that the object holds will be gone.

Answer (score 1):

```
public ArrayList<JobPostBean > al_JobPostBean = new ArrayList<JobPostBean >(); // Declare as global
```

At first Hold Data in ArrayList .If you want delete all data then You can Clear **[ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)**

```
 al_JobPostBean.clear();
```

> The clear() method removes all the elements of ArrayList .

Comment: So, I can't clear the pojo class without declaring the ArrayList?
Also, would the pojo class get cleared if I clear the Arraylist?

Comment: Well I don't think I would require this as I tried  fluffyBatman's solution and it worked. I re-initiated the class and the data were cleared. Thanks @fluffyBatman

Comment: @SomnathPal Move ahead .